# WordPress Loop By Tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to implement a page that displays blog posts by tag using a WordPress loop. The problem that I've been running into is setting the tag to display as the page title. Here is the code that I've tried so far.

```
<?php query_posts('tag=aetna'); ?>
<?php  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="page-content ">
<?php the_content() ;?>
</div>

<?php endwhile; endif ;?>
```

This code works just fine. However, when I try to assign the tag to the page title, it doesn't work. Here is the code I've tried for that. I'm new to PHP so I'm hoping this is just a silly syntax thing.

```
<?php $tag=strtolower(the_title()); ?>
<?php query_posts('tag=$tag'); ?>
<?php  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="page-content ">
<?php the_content() ;?>
</div>

<?php endwhile; endif ;?>
```

Any help you can provide me is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using single quotes with PHP the variable wont be inserted into the string.

Try using the double quotes:

```
<?php query_posts("tag=$tag"); ?>
```

More info here:
[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: Thank you! It is now actually displaying posts. Not the correct ones but I think this has something to do with the page titles and not the loop. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
$tag=strtolower(the_title());
```

should be

```
$tag=strtolower(get_the_title());
```

[**the_title();**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) echos the output while [**`get_the_title();`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) returns it refer Links for more

Comment: And this just solved the problem that I mentioned in my last comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the_title() before the loop. 
It is a function that can only be called inside of the loop.

If you want to use that function you would have to create two queries, one that assigns $tag

`<?php $tag=strtolower(the_title()); ?>`

and the rest in another loop

```
<?php query_posts('tag=$tag'); ?>
<?php  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="page-content ">
<?php the_content() ;?>
</div>

<?php endwhile; endif ;?>
```